# EC2 Django instance ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE from outside

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance working with NGinx and Gunicorn.

Nginx is running fine.

Gunicorn is running fine.

Django app is running fine.

When i `curl -v 127.0.0.1:80` on the machine, i receive the home page. OK.

But when i `curl -v my_public_ip:80` or `curl -v my_public_dns :80` i got unreachable error.

So i simplify my nginx configuration with

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_public_dns my_public_ip;
    return 200;
}
```

to reduce errors to the minimum.

It's still the same error.

My iptable :

```
sudo iptables -vnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    6   340 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 flags:0x17/0x02 ctstate NEW
    2   120 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080 flags:0x17/0x02 ctstate NEW
```

80 port is obviously open in EC2 instance's security group.

Firewall is ok.

```
sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

Telnet :

```
telnet my_public_dns 80
Trying my_public_ip...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

So it doesn't seem to be some of firewall, port, nginx, gunicorn error.
I'm stuggling on it for few days ago.

Comment: Could you please clarify: Nginx, Gunicorn and Django are all running on the same EC2 instance that is in the public subnet?

Comment: Hi Alex., Yes, all these services are running on the same instance on the same subnet.

Comment: `public_dns_address` is the public DNS address of the EC2 instance?  (I assume `my_public_dns` is the same value?)

Comment: Yes that's exact !

Comment: Ohh so weird, it seems to be good right now. I've just rebooted the machine and all seems to be good, don't know why (all services have already been restarted x times to troubleshoot the problem, and i think i have already rebooted the instance also). Now i have a DNS problem, but i think that's the DNS poropagation delay. So i'll wait for that and i hope it'll be ok. Sorry to have wasted your time.